# Geb_Spock tests integration with jenkins

Tags: geb

How to integrate my geb spock tests with jenkins?
I created a jar using **gradlew build** command but only 1kb jar file was created in which there are no .class files.

My folder structure: src/test/groovy
Build automation tool : Gradlew
Framework: Spock
Browser automation tool : Geb

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use [Gradle plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin)?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Any links or so would be helpful.

Comment: If you're using Gradle as your build tool than all you need to do to integrate with Jenkins is to use the aforementioned plugin and run the `test` task.

Comment: My problem is not gradle related at all actually. Though if you could check out my issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221272/configuring-geb-and-spock-on-jenkins-grails) that would help a lot!