# Configuring Geb and Spock on Jenkins (Grails)

Tags: grails, jenkins, spock, geb

I cannot use port 8080 for my testing. When I set the port to another open port (8090) Geb-Spock tests work fine, but only while running locally on IntelliJ. However, if I try and run a Jenkins build, I come out empty handed. I am pretty certain the problem has something to do with my GebConfig.groovy.

Note: I am using xvfb to aid the browser, and I am fairly certain it is configured correctly as it is producing results when configured to 8080.

Running on port 8090...
[image]

Running on port 8080...
[image]

Attempted Solutions:

1. Specify which port to use in Jenkins run configuration (which seems to get the server running just fine)

   - grails -Dgrails.server.port.http=8090 test-app functional: -echoOut --refresh-dependencies
   - There is also an option in the Jenkins grails build to set the port, which works just as well
   - peform a grails clean before running
2. Various configurations within GebConfig.groovy, including changing the baseUrl

   - The first example from Book of Geb

   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
   driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }

   - The geb-grails example - https://github.com/geb/geb-example-grails/blob/master/test/functional/GebConfig.groovy
3. No GebConfig at all

Other info:

- Grails Version: 2.3.6
- Java Version: 1.7.0_79 (open jdk)
- OS: Fedora 20 (local), Ubuntu server 12 lts (Jenkins)
- IntelliJ: 14.0

BuildConfig.groovy

```
dependencies{

    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:0.10.0"

    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.45.0"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.45.0"
}

plugins{
    test ":geb:0.10.0"
}
```

Comment: How can you tell that the failures you're getting are related to a wrong base url? If the port in that url was wrong then you would not get an invalid page title but no title at all. You can print `geb.build.baseUrl` system property in your geb spec to see what the exact used url is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. For some reason it started working this morning. Not really sure why though :/